# not able to execute ifelse statement inside case statement

Tags: bash

I have an if else statement inside 3 parts of a switch statement. I have assigned a command output to a variable based on the output it selects. But it always executes the wildcard *) case and not the other three.

```
case "$ROLE" in
        server )
                  if [[ ("$a" == 1) && ("$b" == 1) && ("$c" == 1) && ("$d" == 1) && ("$e" == 1) && ("$f" == 1) ]]
                  then
                     echo 'statement'
                  else
                     echo 'statement'
                   fi
                   ;;
       server1 )
                  if [[ ("$a" == 1) && ("$b" == 1) ]]
                  then
                     echo 'statement'
                  else
                     echo "statement"
                  fi
                  ;;
        server2 )
                  if [[("$a" == 1) && ("$b" == 1) && ("$c" == 1) && ("$d" == 1) && ("$g" == 1) && ("$h" == 1)]]
                  then
                      echo 'statement'
                  else
                      echo "statement"
        *) 
         echo "unknown"
esac
```

Expected behavior is to execute one of the of the 3 cases but currently the wildcard case statement is executed every time.

Comment: Hi Vel, would you please give an example input for $ROLE. Also since none of your if else statements are ever reached you could make this a more minimal example by just removing them and having a single echo for each case.

Comment: Also I suspect the problem is your whitespace after "sever", "server1" and "server2" between each case and the closing parentheses

Comment: your code is missing some `fi`and some `;;`.

Comment: [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) is your friend. Use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you were almost there...

```
case "$ROLE" in
        server ) if [[ ("$a" == 1) && ("$b" == 1) && ("$c" == 1) && ("$d" == 1) && ("$e" == 1) && ("$f" == 1) ]]
                  then
                     echo 'statement'
                  else
                     echo 'statement'
                   fi
                   ;;
       server1 ) if [[ ("$a" == 1) && ("$b" == 1) ]]
                  then
                     echo 'statement'
                  else
                     echo "statement"
                  fi
                  ;;
        server2 ) if [[ ("$a" == 1) && ("$b" == 1) && ("$c" == 1) && ("$d" == 1) && ("$g" == 1) && ("$h" == 1) ]]
                  then
                      echo 'statement'
                  else
                      echo "statement"
                  fi
                  ;;
        *) echo "unknown";;
esac
```

I just

- put your `if`  statements straight after your case statements (I thought this necessary but apparently is not @biffen)
- terminated your final `if` statement and add `;;` otherwise you will have a syntax error
- and added some spaces

globally your code was ok. I put it in

`test.sh` and then ran

```
ROLE=server bash test.sh
```

getting

```
statement
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. Seems some space issue. Got it. thanks for clarification.

Comment: @VelMurugan if your problem is solved, then please accept then answer. This will show others that the problem is solved.